Help identify the window brand from its sash lock
Located in Sparks, NV.
We are looking for the warranty replacement of a broken sliding window that may be due to quality issue. The window spacer said "2013 13:26 1254756, 003 GBW 0837 ...", and an image of the sash lock is also attached. "2013" I assume to be the year of manufacture.  From what I checked it online it seems to be a Milgard, but when I called they said they could not locate this order.
I am sure the window was not from the original builder because the house was built in 2000.
My Qs:

Is this really a Milgard? If yes, is it possible that the windows were purchased from a local dealer that Milgard may not have records of?
If not, is there a way to find other possible brands from the sash lock? I googled using the pic, but found nothing...




I mean, IDK how much luck you're gonna have without any records, even if the window has a lifetime warranty.

There is no loyalty between window frame and window hardware manufacturers. Even if you found the window manufacturer, they may not keep logs of changes in hardware suppliers or the hardware supplier is no longer in business or the hardware is EOL.

Yeah, sorry... without documentation, no manufacturer is going to warranty a window that's 11 years old.

Thanks for the information! I did confirm it is Milgard. BTW Andersen has the best warranty that still covers my 18-year window.
